# View a post in markdown form without having to click on the edit button

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

In a C++ question, the OP mucked up the `include` line resulting in the header file not showing up in the output (I'm assuming because the pound sign made it bold, and the text in angle brackets was interpreted as an HTML tag.) So I clicked on edit so I could see what the OP meant to include the post, but am unable to because there already is a suggested edit in queue. I can just wait the few minutes but sometimes these edits can take a long time.

Would it be unnecessary to be able to view a post in its "raw" form without having to click on the edit button?

Comment: # is the markdown way to create a heading (`<hN>` with n being the number of hashes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that would only add clutter to the user interface - and it's rarely needed. Besides that, I don't think clicking on "edit" to view the source is a big deal.

However, the greyed-out edit button on meta sites should be replaced with a "view source" link in my opinion (that's the only case where you cannot easily see the source of a post).

Sites like Wikipedia do it just like that: if you can edit you get an edit button, if you can't you just get a view-source button.