# View the raw text of a question/answer

Tags: feature-request, markdown

I am quite aware of [this helpful link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for editing questions and answers, but there are several cases that I would find useful to just copy the raw text of another question/answer. Some examples are:

1. Complex [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) entries about math formulas that I might want to integrate, modify, or copy.
2. On the spot quick reminder of a special uncommon attribute (e.g., HTML)

Is this an already existing functionality?

Comment: @RobertLongson Nice ! this is an actual answer. Didn't thought about it even though I have edited some posts thank you

Comment: Also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329248/how-do-i-get-markdown-source-code-during-a-pending-edit/ https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211683/270345

Comment: @muru I think both answers quite of answer my question but I think I will not delete mine as the reasoning and the phrasing of the question are completely different and someone might reach here

Comment: That's why duplicates exist - questions asking the same thing in different ways. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32311/270345

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on the edit button then copy the text. You don't have to submit the edit.

Comment: An alternative is the "source" link in the revision history (e.g., when logged out, etc.), but I am not sure if it is possible if there aren't any revisions (e.g., to get the GUID to construct the URL). Sample: [`https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/b346575c-fe6d-40f6-96a9-53a6d66cf01c/view-source`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/b346575c-fe6d-40f6-96a9-53a6d66cf01c/view-source)

Comment: Doesn't work if the post is locked, or if you're on a per-site meta and don't have enough rep to edit.